# Can I filter a field from the same row as another in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, parameters, analysis, amazon-quicksight

When a user selects the parameter from the control I added to my dashboard, I want to get a specific field from that exact item and filter my data by that.

I tried setting up a parameter for one field, and the filter it's connected to for another field, but it didn't change anything.

Is there a way to get one piece of data from another, given they're in the same row?

Comment: do you need to use filter controls to accomplish this?

Comment: Also, are you embedding this dashboard or will readers just use the QuickSight page to view it?

Comment: @mjgpy3 I haven't thought that far, right now I just wanted to see if it's even possible to use one field value to refer to a different field,